# Confusion regarding Fermi's golden rule

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, matrix-elements, fermis-golden-rule

The Fermi Golden Rule is:

$$\Gamma_{i\to f}=\frac{2\pi}{\hbar}|\langle f|H'|i\rangle|^2\rho(E_f)$$

In this equation,
$|\langle f|H'|i\rangle|$ is giving information about the coupling.

However, $f$ and $i$ are orthogonal
implying that the term should always yield $0$.

What is probably wrong with my thinking?

Comment: $H'$ is an operator, so $H'\left|i\right>$ is not necessarily orthogonal to $\left<f\right|$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\langle f|i\rangle$ should be zero, but not necessarily $\langle f|H'|i\rangle$. Note also that $|f\rangle, |i\rangle$ are the states of the unperturbed Hamiltonian, $H_0$, not of the full one: $H=H_0+H'$.